# Issue getting regex for 1-10 in string using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm having trouble figuring out what I need to do to get this regex into a string. A page has 10 divs, named info1, info2, info3, etc., through info10.

Here's what I've got but for some reason that'll seem obvious it's not working.

```
data = soup.findAll("div", {"id":"info(r'\d+')}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a *compiled regular expression pattern*:

```
import re

data = soup.find_all("div", {"id": re.compile(r"info\d+")}
```